# MLCC Shortages and Work-Arounds

Tags: capacitor, resistors, pcb-design, mlcc

*I do hope this post is still within the boundaries or spirit of this forum and perhaps this question is best suited for the chat instead.*

I'm sure we all are experiencing (in one form or another) the industry-wide part shortages for discrete MLCC (caps) and resistors, in like the 0402/0603/0805 packages. This part shortage has forced us into sourcing *alternate* parts (sometimes less than ideal) in a effort to continue design work and shipping product.

Here are my two questions. Even though the only research I put forth is Google/web searches for work-arounds; but do any of you designers have any creative methods or ideas in terms of part sourcing or design considerations for providing (mostly) by-passing/de-coupling using 0.1/0.01uF 25V-100V X7R/X5R 0603s in both current product as well as new designs? Should I continue to design in hard-to-find MLCCs and hope this storm blows over sometime soon?

Comment: There are no alternatives. Some warehouses still have plenty though, just not the brand you'd like.

Comment: Where did you get the info about MLCC shortages? In "Fake news"? Why there should be any shortages if there is a demand?

Comment: A 0.1uF cap in 0603 size holding 100V is a real stretch. Use 0805 or 1206 size instead.

Comment: I have heard is that Yageo is no longer producing SMT resistors, but there seem to be plenty of alternatives.  What's the alternative to MLCCs, though?  I do not suggest taking an alarmist stance and replacing 0402 MLCCs with through-hole components.

Comment: On my most recent respin I only found stock issues with caps that pushed the envelope for their package, i.e. 22uF @ 0603, 470nF @ 0201, etc. Your search for 100V 0603s is another example. I just relaxed values where I could and found plentiful stock that way. I'm sure others don't have that luxury though.

Comment: @AliChen The MLCC shortage is very real. You'd encounter it almost immediately trying to buy parts for any volume board with small package caps. Digi-key even puts a note about market demand on all of the MLCC pages. A quick Google search will confirm this for you.

Comment: @AliChen. Here is just one of many articles articulating this shortage. From the horse's mouth as well. https://www.ttiinc.com/content/ttiinc/en/resources/marketeye/categories/passives/me-zogbi-20180302.html

Comment: @AliChen. More "Fake News". http://www.lantekcorp.com/news/multilayer-ceramic-capacitors-shortage-2020?=LAN1807

Comment: Okay, okay, you almost convinced me. I just don't believe that capitalist system is so slow to react to a problem with high demand. This is not a rocket-science technology. I think these articles serve some marketing contract.

Comment: @AliChen Oh you better believe it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can respin your board, there are few things you can do:

- As stated in the comments, use larger package. 0.1uF/100V might be easier to find in 1206 than 0603.
- Use 2 (or more) lower value capacitors instead of one higher value capacitor. Advantage: lower ESR/ESL, Disadvantage: Lower ESR/ESL, depends on your design.
- If allowed and properly evaluated, use different dielectric. Y5V might be easier to source than X7R.
- If you need the higher voltage, use 2 capacitors in series.You will need balancing resistors, which will consume power.
- If cost is not an issue, use Tantalum or other exotic types. Again, this opens up some major reliability concerns, so tread carefully.

Comment: Good stuff, I will take note;-)

Comment: So I relaxed my V-rating, bumped up to 0805s, kept the X7R dielectric (I was using 50V/100V 0603s to keep my library count as low as possible and maximize buying leverage) and can now find more options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use polymer type caps. They outperform MLCCs in a lot of parameters. See https://eu.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidseu/files/pan_18072_whitepaper_mlccvspolymer_web.pdf

Comment: Boy, after reading this white-paper it appears that poly caps may be the silver bullet. When comparing nominal capacitance variance vs DC bias (an artifact that I am still trying to fully understand) those poly caps are superior. This is a big deal in motion-control and stepper drive circuit design.

Comment: A drawback of poly caps is the relatively large leakage current. So they are not a good fit for battery powered applications. But other than that, they are just great (and available!)